# PHP Sqlite script fails on bindparam instruction

Tags: php, function, sqlite, bindparam

I have been looking through similar questions which I have a learnt a thing or two from but I don't seem to be able to make any progress with my problem. I suspect I might be iniating the DB wrong or something like that.

My script gets values from the query string -

```
alarmingwrite5.php?frequency=2&durationChoice=5&hourChoice=8&minuteChoice=30&updateRow=UPDATE+NOW
```

puts them in variables and then it should write the values to the sqlite DB table. There's only one table called alarmTimes and only 4 of the 5 fields need updating.

All seems fine until I bind values to parameters in the update statement.

Any assistance greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET" and isset($_GET['updateRow']))
        {
            updateDB();
        }
        function updateDB()
        {
            $durationChoice = (integer) $_GET["durationChoice"];
            echo gettype($durationChoice).'<br>'; // check type
            $frequency = (integer)  2;
            echo gettype($frequency).'<br>'; // check type
            $hourChoice = (integer) $_GET["hourChoice"];
            echo gettype($hourChoice).'<br>'; // check type
            $minuteChoice = (integer) $_GET["minuteChoice"];
            echo gettype($minuteChoice).'<br>'; // check type

            $db = new SQLite3('/home/pi/sqliteDB/testdbsqlite3.db');
            $statement = $db->prepare("UPDATE alarmTimes SET alarmLength = :alarmLength, alarmCheck = :alarmCheck, alarmHour = :alarmHour, alarmMinute = :alarmMinute where entryID = 1 ");
            echo('prepped</br>'); // This appears
            $statement->bindParam(":alarmLength", $durationChoice, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
            echo('parameter alarmLength bound'); // **** This does not appear so problem is with binding parameters or the values being bound****


            $statement->bindParam(":alarmCheck", $frequency, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
            $statement->bindParam(":alarmHour", $hourChoice, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
            $statement->bindParam(":alarmMinute", $minuteChoice, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
            echo('parameters bound'); // **** This does not appear ****
            $statement->execute();
            echo('executed'); // **** This does not appear ****

            // redirect to same page **** does not happen
            ob_start();
            $url = 'alarmingwrite5.php';
            while (ob_get_status()) 
                {
                    ob_end_clean();
                }
            header( "Location: $url" );

        }
?>
```

Comment: Can you add the error you are getting?

Comment: I deleted my first answer since it wasn't correct and I did not want it to be misleading :)

Comment: @Juan - thanks for the nudge. I turned on display errors, found out it didn't recognise the column in the WHERE condition. Turns out I am an idiot for not writing the DB after changing the structure in DB Browser for SQLite.